# Parse/php-SDK issue with (php 5.3)

Tags: php, parse-platform, composer-php, php-5.3

I have a fatal problem with parse

> "Fatal error: Call to undefined function Parse\session_status() in .. Parse/ParseClient.php on line 73 "

The project worked good in Localhost (php 5.5) . But didnt work on server (php 5.3). 
Unfortunately I can't update my server php engine . What should I do ?

By the way I used composer to install Parse framework . I am not sure if I have any choice to make the framework compatible with php 5.3 .

I am waiting for you suggestions and help guys.
Thank you .

Comment: Adding the code that shows where you are using parse will make it easier to supply an answers.

Comment: Its so normal code . Whenever i try to use parse by for example( $obj=new ParseObject(); ) it gives that error . That error is on the first connect to parse server . It is about checking if a session is open . but in php 5.3 there is nothing like this . thank you  @JasonAller

Answer (score 0):

"Parse/php-SDK" states that it requires PHP 5.4 at least. So this will not work on your 5.3 host unless you provide the patches to the project to make it work.

This is the PHP function that is being used, introduced with PHP 5.4.0: http://php.net/session_status

Note however that support for PHP 5.3 has stopped, no more security fixes, and you should really find a hosting provider that runs a more recent version like 5.5 or 5.6.

Generally you should install the PHP version on your development machine that is being used in production to avoid such neck-breaking experiences of incompatibility.

Comment: thank you for the complete answer but im curious about the pathes you mentioned . how can i get such patches because updating php is not possible on the server as im on shared hosting .

Comment: There are no patches, you would be supposed to develop them.

If you can't upgrade the hosting, you can change the hosting company, or change your development PHP version down to 5.3 and see what is still working and what needs to be replaced,